# Typescript Sequelize, M:M relation, query only returns single entry

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs

I'm using [NestJs](https://nestjs.com/) framework with [Sequelize Typescript](https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript/) for Node where I'm trying to create a many to many relation between a user and a webpage where many users can have the same site in their favorites.

Now my problem is that when I make the query it limits the result to a single entry, while querying the database directly with the exact same query returns all expected entries.

This is my NestJs favorites entity where I define the favorite table:

```
// favorite.entity.ts

import { Table, Column, Model, PrimaryKey, ForeignKey, BelongsTo, NotNull } from "sequelize-typescript";
import { IDefineOptions } from "sequelize-typescript/lib/interfaces/IDefineOptions";
import { UserEntity } from "../users/user.entity";
import { SiteEntity } from "../sites/site.entity";

const tableOptions: IDefineOptions = {
  timestamp: true,
  tableName: "favorites",
  schema: process.env.DB_SCHEMA,
} as IDefineOptions;

@Table(tableOptions)
export class FavoriteEntity extends Model<FavoriteEntity> {
  @BelongsTo(() => UserEntity)
  user: UserEntity;

  @ForeignKey(() => UserEntity)
  @PrimaryKey
  @NotNull
  @Column
  userId: number;

  @BelongsTo(() => SiteEntity)
  site: SiteEntity;

  @ForeignKey(() => SiteEntity)
  @PrimaryKey
  @NotNull
  @Column
  siteId: number;
}
```

And my service where I make the Sequelize query:

```
// favorite.service.ts

import { Inject, Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Model } from "sequelize-typescript";
import { IFavoriteService } from "./interfaces";
import { FavoriteEntity } from "./favorite.entity";

@Injectable()
export class FavoriteService implements IFavoriteService {
  constructor(
    @Inject("FavoriteRepository") private readonly favoriteRepository: typeof Model,
    @Inject("SequelizeInstance") private readonly sequelizeInstance,
  ) {}

  public async findByUserId(userId: number): Promise<FavoriteEntity | null> {
    return await FavoriteEntity.scope().find<FavoriteEntity>({
      logging: console.log,
      where: { userId },
    });
  }
}
```

The logged out SQL statement is:

```
Executing (default): SELECT "userId", "siteId" FROM "public"."favorites" AS "FavoriteEntity" WHERE "FavoriteEntity"."userId" = '1';
```

And results in a single entry as result (there are many rows in the db)...

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "siteId": 1650
}
```

Have I made some mistake in my entity or might it be in my sequelize query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is your result if you use `findAll` instead of `find`.but i am agree the query looks nice

Comment: This worked! I tried it at first too but the Typescript compiler was complaining about a type error, which is a different issue in itself. Just ignoring that for the moment and I got the expected result. Thanks!

Comment: And about the type error, what is the type error when you do findAll<ModelName>()

Comment: The query is correct. But since findAll returns an array I needed to add `findByUserId(userId: number): Promise<FavoriteEntity[] | null> {}` to my method.

Comment: FindAll return an empty array when there is no result and not null

Comment: Ah, might just remove the null then as an empty array is not == (or ===) to null. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[mottosson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1644471/mottosson) are you sure the same sql query returns many rows? Because it will be odd.